# Update users informations during login against LDAP AD using Spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I'm getting the users of my web-app from the `Acive Directory`.
So I created a `custom UserDetailsContextMapper` to save some data of the user to the web-app's MySql Database.

And this is my security configuration about Ldap:

```
   @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth
        .authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }

   @Bean
   public ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
       ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider("myDomain.local", "ldap://LDAP_IP:389/");
       provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
       provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
       provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper());
       return provider;
   }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    }   

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {
        return new LdapUserDetailsContextMapper();
    }
```

I would like to know when and if the data on the `AD` are changed from last login. 
For example if today at 10:00AM I was member of group **A** inside the `AD` and now I'm member of group **A** and **B**, I would like to update the authorities on MySql.

Is there a field or something inside `AD` to know that?

**EDIT:**
I would like to check if something change for a particulare user during the login phase, in this way I can update the information on MySql.

Comment: have you checked notifications on object changes? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772153.aspx

Comment: I would like to check it after during the login phase.. the link that you posted seems relatives to an asynchronous task to check if something change or not... am I wrong?

Comment: as I understand it is possible to register for this kind of notifications, disconnect, and check for changes when you will connect back next time. but i didnt try this myself, so unfortunately could not guarantee that this is 100% sure what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find when a user was last modified, you can use the "whenchanged" attribute.

if you extend LdapUserDetailsMapper, and override the mapUserFromContext, it might look like this:

```
package example.active.directory.authentication;

import org.springframework.ldap.core.DirContextOperations;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsMapper;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;

public class CustomUserMapper extends LdapUserDetailsMapper{

    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities){

        UserDetails details = super.mapUserFromContext(ctx, username, authorities);
        String[] changedValues = ctx.getStringAttributes("whenchanged");

        if(changedValues != null && changedValues.length > 0){
            LocalDateTime lastChangedTime = Arrays.stream(changedValues)
                .map(input ->
                    OffsetDateTime.parse(
                        input,
                        DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuuMMddHHmmss[,S][.S]X")
                    ).toLocalDateTime()
                )
                .sorted((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b) * -1)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
            System.out.println(lastChangedTime);
            //Do something with value?
        }
        return details;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would like to do something similar. How would I use this custom class you have for example to print the attributes of a user from a controller?

Comment: @AlGrant - Even I am also trying to achieve the same, were you able to print the user details from the controller? Can you please provide some inputs?